# I tried serialize() but doesnt seem to work ? what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did this but not working

```
if(error.join()!="")
{
    $("#sub_error").fadeTo(200,0.1,function()
    {
        $("#sub_error").html(error.join("<br/><br/>")).append('<br/>
         <input type="button" name="err_ok" id="err_ok" value="ok">')
         .addClass('subboxerror').fadeTo(900,1);
     bindEvents();
    });

    function bindEvents() 
    {
        $("#err_ok").click(function() 
        {
            $("#sub_error").fadeTo(1000,0);
        });
    }
}
else
{
    $("#frm_sub")
     .removeClass().addClass('messagebox')
     .text('Submitting...').fadeIn("slow");

    $.post("register_user.php",
    { 
        $('#frm1').serialize() 
    } , 
    function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
    });
});
}
```

Comment: a) next time please format your code! b) it seems you have a curly close bracket too many (which you don't see, if you don't format your code properly) c) explain your question in more details. the proportion of code and question should be the other way around!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$.post("register_user.php", $('#theForm').serialize(), function(data) { //...
```

Edit:

You should **not** be wrapping the return value of `('#frm1').serialize()` in curly braces.  The return value of serialize is a string, which the post() call will pass directly to the server.

Comment: Yeah, you have a }, where there should only be a ,

Answer (score 0):

If your input elements come from a form, then you can use the [serialize](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/serialize) method.